# Countries mapped with materials

Tags: pattern, sports

I came across this question a couple of years ago and found it a bit challenging back then. So I thought I will share it with you guys (hope it's not a duplicate):

If

> United States = Concrete
>
> United Kingdom = Grass
>
> France = Clay

Then

> Australia = ?

also, can someone help me with the tags please? :)

Comment: Thanks @Jon-Mark-Perry , but I think that tag spoils it too much :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> Hardcourt (or whatever material it's made off - concrete like for the United States entry?)

Reason:

> Reference to the type of court the matching Grand Slam (tennis) tournaments are played on:  
>  Roland Garros (France) is played on a clay court  
>  US Open (US) is played on hardcourt  
> Wimbledon (UK) is played on grass

Which leaves:

> Australian Open. Which is played on hardcourt.

Comment: Yes, you got the idea, but I think the answer itself could be improved :)

Comment: Yea working on that, just wanted the basic answer in before I got ninja'd.

Comment: You ninja'd me though. :(

Comment: The US open now uses DecoTurf which uses a rubber on top if I remember correctly?

Comment: Yea hardcourt versus concrete is a bit of a stretch. So is gravel/clay for that matter.

Comment: Well, both US open and AUS open use hard court, which is basically concrete or asphalt with some mixture of rubber, acrylic and other stuff o n top :)

Comment: Yea just realised, while i grasped the nature of the question, 'gravel' isn't really correct and should just be 'hardcourt' ? (picking up kid from school, I'll edit accordingly if needed to)

Comment: Well I was expecting "concrete" as for US to be honest, but the question is a bit tricky :)

Answer (score 0):

> Concrete

Because:

> The Grand Slam tennis tournaments are played on hard court (US Open), grass (Wimbledon), clay (Roland-Garros) and concrete again (Australia Open)

Comment: How did that add to the existing answer?

Comment: It doesn't :) But don't block other people to share what they know, not everyone is copying from you.
Or, if you want to have a 1-to-1 talk with the OP, you can ask him for private chat where you can share riddles :)

Answer (score -2):

> Hard court. It's the respective tennis tournaments' court type played in that country.

Comment: Down voted as it is a duplicate of a previous answer which is already accepted.